# How to read in file properly from user input in C?

Tags: c, file, input, file-io

I am trying to read in user input and open the file that the user inputs. My program seems to be exiting right after the print statement. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  printf("What is the name of the file? \n");
  scanf("%s", "fileName");
  FILE* inFile = NULL;
  inFile = fopen("fileName", "r");
  if(inFile == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open this file");
  }
```

Comment: *Never* use `"%s"` as a conversion specifier in scanf.  Doing so is just as bad as using `gets`.

Comment: *Always* check the return value of scanf.

Comment: *Always* provide the system error in your error message, and write error messages to stderr.  `if( inFile == NULL ) { perror(fileName); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` at all, until you understand the pitfalls thoroughly enough to know why it shouldn't be used. Declare a sufficiently size array, e.g. `char line[1024];` and read into line `if (fgets (line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) { /* handle EOF */ }` now simply trim the `'\n'` from the end of line with `line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;` -- done.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 2):

The root of you problem (is using `scanf`, but that's a different issue completely) is:

```
scanf("%s", "fileName");
```

That should be:

```
char fileName[128];
if( 1 == scanf("%127s", fileName)) ...
```

You cannot write to a string literal, so passing the address of a string literal to scanf is a disaster waiting to happen.   You really should use PATH_MAX instead of the hard coded 128, but then you need to use sprintf to construct the format string, and that seems to detract from this example.  For completeness:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
char fileName[PATH_MAX];
char fmt[64];
snprintf(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%%%ds", PATH_MAX - 1);

if( 1 == scanf(fmt, fileName) ){
    FILE* inFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if( inFile == NULL ){
        perror(fileName); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
}
```

But note that you almost certainly do not want to read the input file from the input stream using `scanf`.  It would be better to take it as a command line argument and have it available in `argv`.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, until you thoroughly understand the pitfalls of `scanf()`, it is recommended you use `fgets()` for all user and file input so that you consume a complete line of input with each read. That way what remains in the input stream does not depend on the conversion specifier used and whether a *matching-failure* occurs. If you then need to extract information from the line read by `fgets()` you can use `sscanf()` and regardless of whether `sscanf()` succeeds or fails, it does not impact what is left in your input stream unread.

All line-oriented input functions, `fgets()` and POSIX `getline()` read and include the `'\n'` as part of the buffer they fill. You simply trim the `'\n'` from the end of the stored line after your call to `fgets()` using `strcspn()` to determine the number of characters before the `'\n'` and then overwrite the `'\n'` with the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` (which is simply ASCII `0`).

You handle user-input or lines read from a file the exact same way. For example, you can prompt the user for a filename, read the input, open the file, and then read all lines in the file as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define on (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    char fname[MAXC], line[MAXC];                   /* storage for filename & line */
    FILE *fp = NULL;                                /* FILE pointer */
    
    fputs ("enter filename: ", stdout);                     /* prompt */
    
    if (!fgets (fname, MAXC, stdin) || *fname == '\n') {    /* check EOF or empty line */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 1;
    }
    fname[strcspn (fname, "\n")] = 0;                       /* trim \n from end */
    
    if (!(fp = fopen (fname, "r"))) {               /* validate file open succeeds */
        perror ("fopen-fname");                     /* fopen sets errno on failure */
        return 1;
    }
    
    putchar ('\n');                                 /* provide space before output */
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {                /* read each line from file */
        line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;             /* trim \n from end */
        puts (line);                                /* output line */
    }
    
    fclose (fp);                                    /* close file when done */
}
```

Note, when taking any type of input, every single step must be validated. Otherwise, if you fail to validate, and an input fails, you will invoke *undefined behavior* if you blindly use the variable containing an indeterminate value.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readfile
enter filename: dat/fleas.txt

My dog has fleas
My cat has none
Lucky cat
```

`fgets()` provides one of the most robust ways to handle input. You can use `scanf()` as well -- so long as you understand each pitfall associated with its use and you protect against it. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fscanf()` function.